# Line Bot subscribeing with parameter?

Tags: direct-line-botframework

Line Bot API Service provied an QRcode for subscribing an channel. Onece User subscribed, the server shell get the subscribed event.
It' seems stupid that telling user to send their user_id in the line channel to link the Line user id.
Is there any way to add parameter to the QRCode for subscribing, such like the user_id, So Bot Server  can recevie it for link the user?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're trying to use Direct Line to connect to LINE. I see where the confusion comes from, but this is not the correct way to connect to LINE.

[Direct Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is a channel that allows you to interact with a bot framework bot directly when one of the other available channels doesn't fit your use case.

It is **not** the same thing as the [LINE channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-line?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), which is how you connect a bot to the LINE messaging platform. Use the linked instructions to connect LINE to your bot.